# How to scope a dependency to ViewModel when using AssitedInjection?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I am creating a ViewModel that has some non transitive dependency parameters in the constructor.

Example:

```
class MyViewModel(
    private val fetchUserUseCase: FetchUserUseCase,
    private val fetchNewsUseCase: FetchNewsUseCase,
    myCustomParameter: String = "",
    myOtherCustomParameter: Long = -1L
) : ViewModel()
```

Due to the last two parameters, I cannot use the `@HiltViewModel` annotation and if I use [`@AssistedInjection`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/assisted-dependency-injection-in-viewmodel-with-dagger-hilt-in-android/) to create a custom ViewModel Factory, when I try to scope some dependency (Example: `FetchNewsUseCase`) to `@ViewModelScoped`, I receive an error like the following one:

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] FetchNewsUseCase cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

How can I make Hilt/Dagger see that `MyViewModel` is a "Hilt ViewModel"?